# How can I see the photo settings like f-stop, ISO etc. of a image?

Tags: aperture, metadata, shutter-speed, iso

I am new to photography and enjoying shooting with my Nikon D3200 camera. Once I take a photo, is there any tool by Nikon or a third party which can give me info like F-stop, ISO, Shutter speed, etc? If there is no tool, does Nikon camera support this after the photo is shot?

Comment: I find it comical that all of the answers thus far have taken this question way beyond the simple :)

Comment: if i remember correctly, when you press Play on D3200 and then press _DOWN_ on selector, it will pop you all stats such as ISO, metering, f-number and shutter speed

Comment: @aandreev - Kind of like my answer below? Ha

Comment: exactly, I didn't scroll that far %) but upvoted yours as most sane

Answer (score 11):

Your camera saves this information, which we call "metadata" (because it is data *about* the data captured in the photo itself — one level beyond, or *meta*), in every file. There are many utilities which can read and display this. I'm not aware of any software designed for photography which *doesn't* — that'd include Adobe Photoshop and Lightroom, Picassa, and any image viewer. You can also get stand-alone programs which can manipulate this metadata in various ways, including editing or removing it, or giving you different presentations (like, "find all the photographs I took with a certain lens").

But, in fact, almost all modern operating systems have a mechanism for showing this information built in. Just open the folder on your computer and then, when you see the list of files:

- In Microsoft Windows: right click on a file, choose `Properties`, and then look in the `Details` tab.
- In Mac OS X, right click — or command-i — and then click the triangle by `More Info` to expand.
- In GNOME, as in the Fedora Linux operating system, right click, choose `Properties`, and go to the `Image` tab.

Again, each of these operating systems — and not to mention Chromium, iOS, or Android — will have more advanced utilities. But you can see the basic information right there without anything extra.

Comment: Or 'Alt+Enter' for properties in Windows.

Answer (score 8):

Once you take a photo, you can view **Photo Information** by clicking the `Play` button on the back of your D3200 and clicking the `Arrow` either up or down.

More information can be found on [page 98 of your manual](http://cdn-10.nikon-cdn.com/pdf/manuals/dslr/D3200_EN.pdf). Aperture, Shutter speed, ISO, Focal Length, Focus Mode, Flash Mode, White Balance, and much more is all available via this menu.

[image: Manual Info]

Answer (score 5):

(I think) Every digital photo has aditional data stored on it besides the image itself. That is called **Exif data** (Exchangeable image file format).

A Dslr camera can shoot to a raw or jpg image file, and both formats include this data. Smartphones and compact cameras most likely shoot only in jpg, but it includes this information too.

When you manipulate the photo some file formats preserve this data, in some cases this data is replaced and in some other cases all data is lost, but I repeat, after manipulating the image.

You can read this exif data in some image viewer. For example, the viewer I use the most (in windows) is Irfanview http://www.irfanview.com/. In the Menu > Image > Information You can see all this data.

Another good viewer is XnView http://www.xnview.com/en/. You can see the exif data in a tab called ExifTool.

Inside Photoshop > File > File Info.

Comment: **Most** every digital photo...you and I can easily scrub this data for whatever reason. I also imagine that *certain* firmware can allow a user to omit that data. That is nitpicking though and I'll give it a +1.

Comment: I added "I think". :o)

Answer (score 2):

There are many tools which can provide you this information: Lightroom, xnview, (probably) any graphic editor.

Also any EXIF tool can provide you this info (check exiftool, its free and very good)

P.S. For sure there is Nikon instrument, which can provide you such information, but I am not Nikon shooter :)

Answer (score 2):

At least on windows, you can see a lot of EXIF info in the file properties, details tab.

Answer (score 2):

Nikon have free Nikon ViewNX-i: http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Nikon-Products/Product/Imaging-Software/ViewNX-i.html
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I usually

1. Right-click on the photo.
2. Scroll down to **Properties**.

   All the relevant information will then come up.