# Image Viewer With with Exif

Tags: metadata, exiftool, photo-viewer

Looking for something like windows photo viewer where I can open an image from a folder and page through the images in that folder using next, previous, but also have the EXIF info show up somewhere.

Rather now have to right click to look at properties, would like the exif info to show up somewhere each time i open an image.

I understand the details view of windows explorer shows this info with a thumb, but looking for a viewer that shows full scree\best fit of image with exif.

Free would be nice too!

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I see the photo settings like f-stop, ISO etc. of a image?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/63480/how-can-i-see-the-photo-settings-like-f-stop-iso-etc-of-a-image)

Comment: @RomeoNinov This is certainly not a duplicate of the question referenced. The other asks how to view EXIF information. This asks how to do it persistently while stepping through photos. Some offerings do that very poorly or not at all. There are no doubt a number of good solutions and hearing of a few more would be useful. I went into the detail I did because it's only "trivially obious obvious in retrospect" and the options of customisable format or std screen on second monitor are both useful.  I like the custom format as I can maximise readability know exactly where to look when scanning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be many good options. This is what I happen to use usually and it works well for me. It would be useful to hear from other people too.

[**Irfanview**](http://www.irfanview.com) does this well.
And its marvellous in general, and it's free.
I get scolded by Matt for enthusing over its slide show, resizing, basic organising and editing and more, so I won't :-). (It's OK to do this for Photoshop, I think.)

The amount of data in the EXIF block is astounding. To display it all at readable resolution would dominate the screen.

With Irfanview there are (at least) two methods. the options of customisable format or std screen on second monitor are both useful.  I like the custom format as I can maximise readability (for me)(and you can for you) and  know exactly where to look when scanning through photos at speed. Size and format can be varied to suit. The ugly block at screen top can be toggled on/off essentially instantaneously as required (keyboard being vastly superior to 'mouse' for such things as the brain can repetitively position and move fingers for N point selection far faster than it can semi-randomly move the hand/finger combination required for N point mouse selection).

(1) You can create an on-screen display of any subset of the EXIF data that you wish. 
This can be located in one of 4 (I think) standard positions - I always use upper left - and can be sized to suit, a desired font and text colour can be selected and the text and background can be made opaque or semi opaque.

A challenge when using semi opaque text and/or background is finding a combination that is rapidly readable for all images. After much experimenting I've chosen to use an opaque background which makes for good readability at the cost of obscuring part of the image. 
The text display can be toggled on/off with a single key press ("N") so it is easy to display it or not as desired.

Depending on task I may change the EXIF set and formating, but my normally used combination is as below. I save variations in a text file so that I can change them easily when desired. :

**This is my standard setup:**
Rather than explain the various EXIF codes used a picture of the result will be more informative. Spacing affects the result and the initial leading "." is part of the show (stopping leading space trimming on the first line.)

[image]

Which does this.
I realised only after labelling that I had screen captured this on a lower horizontal resolution screen than I usually use and the flash message has folded onto a new line.

[image]

In addition to the above:
EXIF view can be toggled on and off using "E"
and another subset with "I"
and full IPTC data fields access with another I.

(2). If using dual monitors the standard EXIF screen can be displayed on one while stepping through images on the other, thusly - the displayed EXIF data changes with each new image selected. This has the disadvantage of providing the first 27 or so EXIF fields of the programmers choice -which are useful but may not match what you want. he custom string method allows daata to be subset exactly as desired. The very ken may be able to modify Irfanview so that user selected EXIF data is provided on the standard screen. Irfan Skiljan accepts competent modifications that he likes so this may be a real option.

Dual screens. Photo on left, EXIF and other stuff on right.

[image]

Comment: That's...a lot of hard drives you have. I'm willing to bet it is over 15TB. How do you keep everything oranized?

Comment: @SailorCire That was meant to obscure other stuff - not to provide information :-). 33TB + a small SSD. Photos the main size driver. "With great difficulty". Currently rationalising usage with smaller older drives being slowly combined onto larger ones. Mix of 1 1.5 2 3 4 TB. NO formal mirroring. At least two copies of historically stable folders (usually more) on separate drives. One or more mirrors of annual or semi annual folders of by-event and by-date folders. | XXCOPY is your great friend! | Run an occasional index run over all photo folders to create about 500 GB searchable index ...

Comment: ... files. Works. Lose about nothing (as far as I know :-) ) so far in 15 years and can find almost any photo or event I can remember a small amount about. (Meaningful naming of folders plus a few seed long named photos helps). Works for me. Better exists.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I have to ask: do you rate all of your photos out of five/ten and, if so, how many do you have in total which have a perfect score?

Comment: @Arkanon - I don't rate out of N but none have a perfect score.| Rating scheme(s) that count most are: (1) Photos I've taken that I like a lot.   (2) Photos from 1. that other people like. (3) MAYBE some photos from 2. that are not in 1. | When the bride / person turned 21 / similar keeps saying "The photos are fantastic" I feel I may be winning. (Not TOO common. Twice lately. Happenstace) |My perhaps most 'popular' photo, that I like but am surprised at the reaction to, is of Kangaroos. My (arguably) all time favourite photo would be passed by by most and I'm not 100% sure why I rate it so.